# viewing Original Object under synonyms

Tags: schema, view, oracle-sql-developer

I have certain synonyms in my schema which represent views from another schema. Now in oracle sqldeveloper, I am unable to see the actual SQL for those views but I see only an SQL like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM "ABC"."ABC_CHAR" FOR "XYZ"."ABC_CHAR";
```

Now my question is: is there a way for me to see the Actual SQL for the View `XYZ.ABC_CHAR` that is in the other schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tree view on the left-hand-side, expand the tree for your database connection. Expand  "Other Users", then "XYZ", then "Views". Double-click on the view name "ABC_CHAR" - this will open the column list. Click "SQL" above the column list to see the query that created the view.

The other way to achieve this is to use SQL:

```
select text 
from all_views
where owner='XYZ' 
and view_name = 'ABC_CHAR';
```

This all assumes you have the correct grants to see the view text.